# Testing net/http?

Tags: testing, go

I am a little confused about how to structure a go web app and its tests. I have read the [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) but still don't get it. For example, I have a go project called "beacon" with a `beacon.go` file at the root. Adding a trivial `beacon_test.go` file (copied verbatim from http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server) causes this error:

```
$ go test
# github.com/jelder/beacon
./beacon_test.go:11: main redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./beacon.go:216
FAIL    github.com/jelder/beacon [build failed]
```

Sure enough, line 11 is `func main()`. If I instead change the `package main` line in my `beacon_test.go` to `package hello`, I get this error instead:

```
can't load package: package github.com/jelder/beacon: found packages main (beacon.go) and hello (beacon_test.go) in /Users/jacob/src/github.com/jelder/beacon
```

Answer (score 1):

`beacon_test.go` has also a function called `main()` rename it to `TestFirst` (or any other name you like as long as it starts with `Test`, note the uppercase `T` is important). There is no need for that. Just run `go test .` from inside the package you are working on (the one containing the *.go files). Post the full files if you need more help.